# Android studio @strings not working

Tags: android

In my android project none of my @string variables are not working.

For example in the title bar I see **@string/app_name** instead of **myapp**.

In my AndroidManifest.xml it looks normal, with the line `android:label="@string/app_name"`

Also, in my layout buttons and textviews show @string/action_sign_in but they also have the line in there xml layout. `android:text="@string/action_sign_in"`

Anyone had this issue before?

Comment: Build again your app

Comment: make sure `<string name="action_sign_in">Neel</string>` is availbale in `string.xml` file

Comment: Yep got     <string name="action_sign_in">Sign in or register</string>
in my strings.xml

Comment: @Kaigo share your layout file ans string.xml file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clean, rebuild verify if its working.

If not, you can alt+enter on the @string/action_sign_in redline and click on create string value resource then set the value to the string.

Comment: clean, rebuild didn't make a difference. There is no red line under                 android:text="@string/action_sign_in". It doesn't complain at all.

Comment: Okay there was a little red sign in preview layout and it had auto fix option. Bit confused but its working now. Thanks